# Jagged plot lines with proper group set (ggplot in R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create line graph with the following code:

```
    ggplot(lnewdat, aes(x = Cl, y = Probability, colour = Level, group = Level)) + geom_smooth(stat = 'identity') + facet_grid(Species~Year)
```

I get the a graph that looks similar to this graph:

[image: graph]

When looking up a solution to the jagged lines, everything mentions setting the "Group". As you can see from my code, I have already done that. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: It looks like there should be two lines in each facet. Is there another variable in the data that you are not showing us (it's impossible to answer this kind of question without seeing the data)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.